# i am trying to sort a vector of certain user defined data type but it is giving me syntax error c++

Tags: c++

While solving a certain ds algo question,I had to sort the array using a custom comparator.I don't know why is it showing me errors at that particular line

**Code**

```
 #include"bits/stdc++.h"
 using namespace std;
 struct train{
      
      int platform,arrive,depart;
 };
 bool compare(train x,train y)
 {
     
     return x.depart<y.depart;

 }
 int maxTrains(vector<train> arr[])
 {
     int ans=0;
     sort(arr,arr+arr.size(),compare);
     return ans;
 }
 int main()
 {
     return 0;
 }
```

**Error message:**
no instance of overloaded function "sort" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::vector<train, std::allocator> *, , bool (train x, train y))[13,6]

{
"resource": "/F:/programming/dsa cracker sheet/maximum trains for which stoppage can be provided/max-trains.cpp",
"owner": "C/C++",
"code": "153",
"severity": 8,
"message": "expression must have class type but it has type "std::vector<train, std::allocator> *"",
"source": "C/C++",
"startLineNumber": 13,
"startColumn": 19,
"endLineNumber": 13,
"endColumn": 22
}[13,19]

Comment: guess: `int maxTrains(vector<train> arr[])` error is in this line.

Comment: `vector<train> arr[]` This is most definitely not what you want.

Comment: whats wrong in that?

Comment: That will create an array of vectors, however, you just want a single vector to store all `train` objects. Think of a vector as an array which can be resized. So you are sending a 2-D array of trains to be sorted, which I guess is not what you intended to do. I believe you wanted to send an array of trains, and sort them according to their time of departure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong.
First, This line is really saying `vector<train>* arr`, Pointer to a vector. But you used `vector` so array and memory management is totally internal to it. And you are using `sort` which is in-place sorting algorithms means, it modifies the original array, so you have to pass it via reference.

```
int maxTrains(vector<train> arr[])
```

This is the correct way.

```
int maxTrains(vector<train>& arr) //if you want modify original
```

Second, are you using sort which expects `sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, compare);` This is how you call `std::sort`.

```
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(),compare);
```

This is what you want, the rest works fine. I do not know what exactly you want to do with `maxTrain` so I am just fixing the errors.

```
 int maxTrains(vector<train>& arr)
 {
     int ans=0;
     sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(),compare);
     return ans;
 }
```

Using these lines is a very bad practice.

```
#include"bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
```

Try to be explicitly as much as you can, this way you can learn more.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cleaner approach. Your `maxTrains` function returns an `int` that is never set within the function. You simply need to sort the `vector`.

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;
 
 struct train
 {
    int platform;
    int arrive;
    int depart;
 };
 
 bool compare(const train& x, const train& y)
 {
     return x.depart < y.depart;
 }
 
 void maxTrains(vector<train>& vec)
 {
     sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare);
 }
 
 int main()
 {
     return 0;
 }
```

For `compare` be sure to pass by reference so you're not making copies of the object. The `maxTrains` functions needs the `vector` to be passed by reference so it can be modified, sorted, and returned. Also, be sure to include the correct header files.

Answer (score 1):

Following changes will remove all compile time errors, however, logically your code will still have flaws.

```cpp
 #include"bits/stdc++.h"
 using namespace std;
 struct train{
      
      int platform,arrive,depart;
 };
 bool compare(train x,train y)
 {
     
     return x.depart<y.depart;

 }
 int maxTrains(vector<train> arr) // change from array of vectors to single vector
 {
     int ans=0;
     sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),compare); // use arr.begin() and arr.end()
     return ans;
 }
 int main()
 {
     return 0;
 }
```

1. The vector you are sending to `maxTrains` is sent using pass-by-value, so any changes done by the function will not be reflected back in the calling function
2. You are not calling `maxTrains` function

Comment: Yeah I was planning to write the code for driver function ,but I thought it would be a good idea to first resolve the visible syntax errors

Comment: @coder_newbie Just make sure to send `arr` using pass-by-reference, otherwise, sorting will occur, but the changes wont be reflected back in the driver function

Comment: @AnubhavGupta *Following changes will remove all compile time errors* -- No it doesn't -- `#include"bits/stdc++.h"` -- That will not compile on the compiler I'm using, Visual C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The OP seems to be using G++. "bits/stdc++.h" is only available in G++.  For Visual C++ you can use <vector> and <algorithm>